# Bootstrap Collapse Menu Troubles -- Doesn't push content OR display proper inverse background color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new both to SO and Boostrap, but I made sure to try a number of previous solutions to my problem and it seems I've created a unique problem for myself as none of the solutions SEEMED to have worked for me. Hopefully I'm not just missing something silly but here's my Bootstrap code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <header class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">JMG Photography</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </header>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <!--Home-->
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="guess">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about the problem(s) you're having: based on the code you posted it isn't clear because the color and toggle work as expected. Have you included all the required dependencies? (CSS/JS/jQuery) See [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included) and [mcve]

Comment: I edited the code-base. I didn't think about your needing some content for it to dip into.

Comment: I still don't see what you're referring too as far as **"dip into"**. I edited your question so the code runs. Please check it because it displays as it should according to the defaults.

Comment: That works now. Mine wasn't working. Could it be something as simple as my JS script references being wrong? My script references are different in my original code base?